# How can I get the 95% simultaneous confidence interval for four proportions?

Tags: r, inference

300 male high school students are surveyed on their smoking frequencies, the results are following:
Frequency     (1)never smoke   (2) 1-4/day   (3) 5-10/day   (4)more than 10/day
Number of people    168          85             30              17
So how can I get the simultaneous confidence interval of the proportions of the four kinds of people above? It can't be better if R code is provided.

Comment: You are dealing with a multinomial distribution where $p_4$ = 1 - ($p_1$ + $p_2$ + $p_3$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched "simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial distribution" and got much richer results. [link](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/15/confidence-intervals-multinomial-proportions.html) tells me some methods used in this problem and I found **MultinomCI** in R can solve this problem.